# Getting stuck trying to get back to the prison on the second runthrough

Tags: dead-island

I have completed the game once, and I'm towards the end of my second run through the game, but I seem to be stuck. There are no missions available, and no way for me to get back to the prison to continue the story and complete it again.

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Will someone be able to help me?

Comment: What was your most recently completed (main, non-sidequest) story mission?

Comment: I was playing through the story normally and 'helping the Scientists' in the lab. But i have no flags or '!' to go to for missions. I have been round back to all areas (jungle, slums.. etc) in case i had missed something but no

Answer (score 1):

When you load the save or reload a checkpoint, you will be inside the laboratory, facing the door to Dr. West's office, go inside the office and open the small fridge opposite the door and take the antidote. After that you will need to interact with the radio on the table to go to prison (don't pass go).

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that you accidentally fast travelled out of the prison by loading last checkpoint while highlighting a mission not in the prison. However, I would've expected you to return to the prison the next time that you load up the save file from the title menu.

If you've already been to the prison on that playthrough, fast travel maps will allow you to fast travel to the prison. kotekzot's theory that you haven't retrieved the antidote sounds slightly plausible too. In any case, you can click play at the title menu, new game, pick the same character, choose the chapter closest to your progress, which sounds like chapter 16 which is the start of the prison, as desireable, and select your old character's data to play with. Don't worry, this creates a copy of the save file.

Answer (score 0):

Dead Island fix for PC. stuck at laboratory can't get to prison . at the prison cutscene quit the game now I'm stuck radio doesn't work. I fixed it by doing the following: goto out folder  in install directory and backup save and profiles folders in another folder. now start the game and select new game from menu select chapter 16 with the same character. you now have no inventory to money but you are at the prison. halfway there... quit the game completely out to Windows. start the game and select Continue you are now at the prison or somewhere else. now quit the game only to main menu and ALT and tab out to Windows. now replace the profiles and saves folders that you have backed up while the game is running.  alt  and  tab back to the game select Continue and you should now be at the start of the prison quest with all your items and money and levels.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on the PS3 edition. But when I walked around (from lab to the boat, where you can store your items with Jin, and back) it came up by itself.

Was just wandering to find that flower, already having a ton of them. Then I fell from a rocky cliff and respawned.  Later on when close to the lab I saw a "!" on the little map. So just walk around for 10-15 minutes and it will, I think, solve itself.